# How to build a field list in a node?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have two content types: 'artist' and 'venue'.

When an artist node is viewed, it needs to display a list of venues and dates. Venue name will link to the venue node eg:

```
Artist
-------------------- 
Venue1 | 1-Jan 20:00
Venue2 | 2-Jan 17:00
Venue3 | 4-Jan 20:00
```

The possible solutions are:

1. Create a 'performance' content type that links (using the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module) to artist and venue, and has a date field. Then attach the list using Views. This seems like a lot of extra work for the editor.
2. Add two unlimited value fields to artist node: reference to venue and date field. It is difficult to keep them in sync and clunky.
3. Would this be a good use of the entity API? I don't know enough about entities yet, but have a feeling that would be overkill for something so simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)?
You can create collection with Node Reference field and Date field. Then [Field Collection Table](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_table) will help you with outputting.
This exactly works with Entity API.